# Spring Task Scheduling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I want to implement task scheduling using spring boot. I am NOT so experienced with the spring framework. I have seen simple examples using annotations like @EnableScheduling, @Scheduled(...).

But in my project, I want to customize these tasks using JSON configuration file so that I don't need to build and deploy spring project every time task is changed.
One sample JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    "jobs":{
          "job":{
                "enabled":true,
                 "name": "myJob",
                 "trigger":{
                    "type":"periodic",
                     "initialDelay":1000,
                     "fixedRate":15000
                    },
                   "target": {
                           "id":"task_name",
                            "class":"com.frietec.tasks.MyTask"
                    }
                }                                     
         }
}
```

We can define as many tasks as we need which are defined in com.frietec.tasks package.

This configuration gives me the flexibility of tasks management, for example enable or disable tasks, delay settings etc.  This configuration is located somewhere in the server and spring project reads this file and schedules the task according to the configuration. This way gives me another advantage of deploying a single war file and simply manage the tasks from the customer configured task configuration.

Yes, this is what I want to implement in my project, and I need your ideas or suggestions on how we can achieve this using spring task scheduling.